# Can I do arpana of a chola (cloth) to shri hanuman ji in the morning?

Tags: rituals, hanuman, puja

Because people say that we should only do it in evening. Then what should be done?

Comment: If as per beliefs it has to be done during evening then why you want to do the offering during day?

Comment: @Rickross is it true? Coz I do chola arpan during morning.

Comment: Source for doing it only in evening?

Comment: I was going by what Aditya Gupta wrote. I don't have any experience of my own. If the custom is to offer chola during evening then why to go against that custom? If however someone can refute the claim itself from a valid source then that should be posted as an answer @RishX

Comment: @Rickross ohh. Nevermind. Actually I have heard people say that Lord Hanuman should be worshipped in evening only (not just chola arpan but normal worship as well). Even one Panditji told the same. As Hanumanji is busy in service of Sri Rama during day. That's why only evening prayers are answered by Hanuman Ji. But I can't find any scriptural source for the same.

Comment: Yes I have also seen the same. Hanuman worship is usually done in the evening. @RishX